# Отличия ThreadPoolExecutor от ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Имеется парсер на Selenium Webdriver.

Имеется код:

```
def crawl():

    while True:
        urls = list_product.copy()
        list_product.clear()
        print(urls)

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
            for _ in executor.map(parsing, urls):
                pass
        if len(list_product) == 0:
            break
```

При парсинге, в случае если найдены Url, к ним тоже нужно применить parsing и т.д, найденные Url добавляются в глобальный list_product.

Я хотел посмотреть, как себя поведет при ProcessPoolExecutor, но почему то при его использовании, не определяются ссылки, которые видны при ThreadPoolExecutor

Полный код:

```
    import logging
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor

count_thread = os.cpu_count()


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

input_categories = "categories.txt"
main_url_site = "https://spb.vseinstrumenti.ru"

products = []

list_product = []
getting_url = []

def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/geckodriver.exe"
    option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    option.add_argument("--headless")
    # chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # chrome_option.add_argument("headless")
    # prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    # chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


    try:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff, options=option)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=chrome_option)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, chrome_options=chrome_option, service_args=service_args)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver

def check_url(url):
    if url in getting_url:
        return False
    else:
        getting_url.append(url)
        return True

def add_product(code, price):
    global products
    if(price is not None):
        temp = {"id": code, "price": price}
        products.append(temp)



def get_categories(input_filename):

    with open(input_filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            list_product.append(line)


def parsing(url):

    driver = init_driver()
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        getting_url.append(url)
        print("Обработанная ссылка:",url)

        #Раздел поиска категорий
        urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.fs-15.c-black")
        if len(urls) > 0:
            for url in urls:
                if url not in getting_url:
                    href = url.get_attribute("href")
                    list_product.append(href)
                    print(href)

        else:
            urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.name > a")
            if len(urls) > 0:
                for url in urls:
                    if url not in getting_url:
                        href = url.get_attribute("href")
                        list_product.append(href)
                        print(href)
            else:
                urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.valign-t > td.valign-t > div > a")
                if len(urls) > 0:
                    for url in urls:
                        href = url.get_attribute("href")
                        list_product.append(href)
                        print(href)

                else:
                    #Раздел поиска продуктов
                    items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.list-box.product")
                    if(len(items) > 0):
                        for item in items:
                            href = item.find_element_by_css_selector("div > div.product-name > a").get_attribute(
                                "href")
                            if(check_url(href)):
                                try:
                                    code = item.find_element_by_css_selector("div.list-left > div.header > div.code > span").text
                                except:
                                    code = None

                                try:
                                    price = item.find_element_by_css_selector(
                                        'div.price > div.ns > div.price-actual > span.amount').text
                                    if price.find(" ") != -1:
                                        price = price.replace(" ", "")
                                except:
                                    price = None
                                add_product(code, price)
                                print("Код:", code, "Price:", price)
                    else:
                        items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.tile-box.product")
                        if (len(items) > 0):
                            for item in items:
                                href = item.find_element_by_css_selector("div > div.product-name > a").get_attribute("href")
                                if(check_url(href)):
                                    try:
                                        code = item.find_element_by_css_selector(
                                            "div > div.header > div.code > span").text
                                    except Exception as e:
                                        code = None
                                    try:
                                        price = item.find_element_by_css_selector('div.price > div.ns > div.price-actual > span.amount').text
                                        if price.find(" ") != -1:
                                            price = price.replace(" ", "")
                                    except:
                                        price = None
                                    add_product(code, price)
                                    print("Код:", code, "Price:", price)
                        else:
                            items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.group_row")
                            if len(items) > 0:
                                for item in items:
                                    href = item.find_element_by_css_selector(
                                        "div >  a").get_attribute("href")

                                    if (check_url(href)):
                                        try:
                                            code = item.find_element_by_css_selector(
                                                "div > div.header > div.code > span").text
                                        except Exception as e:
                                            code = None
                                        #Для страниц, где нету code
                                        if code is None:
                                            list_product.append(href)
                                            continue

                                        try:
                                            price = item.find_element_by_css_selector(
                                                'div.price > div.ns > div.price-actual > span.amount').text
                                            if price.find(" ") != -1:
                                                price = price.replace(" ", "")
                                        except:
                                            price = None
                                        add_product(code, price)
                                        print("Код:", code, "Price:", price)



                            else:
                                code = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#aboveImageBlock > span.wtis-id > span.wtis-id-value.codeToOrder").text
                                try:
                                    price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.price-value").text
                                    if price.find(" ") != -1:
                                        price = price.replace(" ", "")
                                except:
                                    price = None
                                add_product(code, price)
                                print("Код:", code, "Price:", price)
                    try:
                        #Только для первой страницы
                        if url.find("page") == -1:
                            pagination = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.paging.dspl_ib.commonPagination")
                            # data_per_page = int(pagination.get_attribute("data-per-page"))
                            data_max_page = int(pagination.get_attribute("data-max-page"))
                            for i in range(2, data_max_page + 1):

                                href = url + "page" + str(i)
                                list_product.append(href)
                                print(href)

                                # "https://spb.vseinstrumenti.ru/instrument/akkumulyatornyj/akkumulyatory/litij_ionnye/page2/"
                    except:
                        print("Pagination не найден")
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

        parsing(url)


def crawl():

    while True:
        urls = list_product.copy()
        list_product.clear()
        print(urls)

        with ProcessPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
            for _ in executor.map(parsing, urls):
                pass
        if len(list_product) == 0:
            break




if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    get_categories(input_categories)
    crawl()
    print("Количество продуктов:", len(products))
    pd.DataFrame(products).to_excel(r'products.xlsx', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

В качестве первоначальной ссылки list_product можно использовать эту ссылку, на которой я увидел странное поведение.

```
https://spb.vseinstrumenti.ru/stroitelnoe_oborudovanie/malyarnoe/ustanovki/
```

Я не понимаю в чем ошибка.

Comment: Потому что у потоков общая память, а у каждого процесса своя.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev что вы можете посоветовать?

Comment: В очередной раз могу посоветовать не использовать глобальные переменные.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev можно ли как нибудь из процесса вернуть результаты?, например метод возвращает список url, и его нужно как нибудь вытащить из 
with ProcessPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
            for _ in executor.map(parsing, urls):
                pass

Comment: Во-первых, `map` возвращает результаты вызова функций. Во-вторых, есть [очереди, каналы и разделяемая память](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).